# create Path for each node in a tree structure dataframe in R

Tags: r

I got a dataframe with around 1 million obs. and 20 variables. Variables include level and Part ID information.
Basically it's like a tree structure dataframe. I want to create path for each row base on the 'level' (level <20). Below is an example, and the column 'Path' is what I want to create. 
I currently use a nested for-loop with if to create the path. It processes each row, so my laptop takes 5 to 6 hours to get the path of a million rows. Any idea on how to get the path more time efficient? Thank you!

```
Level   Part ID   Path
```

```
1       11111    11111
2       22222    11111/22222
3       33333    11111/22222/33333
3       44444    11111/22222/44444
4       55555    11111/22222/44444/55555
2       66666    11111/66666
1       77777    77777
2       88888    77777/88888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this test data

```
dd <- read.table(text="Level   PartID   Path
1       11111    11111
2       22222    11111/22222
3       33333    11111/22222/33333
3       44444    11111/22222/44444
4       55555    11111/22222/44444/55555
2       66666    11111/66666
1       77777    77777
2       88888    77777/88888", header=T)
```

It would probably be the most efficient to do with a single loop. For example

```
get_path <- function(level, part) {
    path <- character(length(level))
    current_parts <- c()
    for(i in seq.int(length(path))) {
        current_level <- level[i]
        current_parts[current_level] <- part[i]
        path[i] <- paste(current_parts[1:current_level], collapse="/")
    }
    path
 }
 get_path(dd$Level, dd$PartID)
```

Comment: Line 5 was a typo, and I updated the original table. Will try this with large data set and see how long it'll take. Thanks MrFlick.

Comment: Tried this with half million lines dataset, and worked perfectly. Took less than one minute, which is exactly what I wanted
!